# UTF8 issue in Android webView.loadUrl

Tags: android, utf-8

My webpage is working in all brwosers including iOS devices.But I use same page in Android app webview the characters are blank.

Original characters: "à´•à´°àµà´£à´¯à´±àµà´± ; à´¨à´¿à´¸àµà´¨àµ‡à´¹à´®à´¾à´¯ ; à´¸àµà´¨àµ‡à´¹à´®à´¿à´²àµà´²à´¾à´¤àµà´¤"

After I use  - meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"   its showing correct words in local language [കരുണയറ്റ ; നിസ്നേഹമായ ; സ്നേഹമില്ലാത്ത]
but the same webpage not shoing in android   webView.loadUrl.

Answer (score 12):

Try using this istead of `webView.loadUrl(...)`:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "yourWebPage ", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

or try this:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
```

Comment: I tried but showing blank value in android app. Please check my code  WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
  settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
  webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.199/Test/android/index.php?p=".concat(val));

Answer (score 3):

Hey i suggest all of you facing unicode problem to test your app on real device mine was not working on emulator but when i tested on real device my app loaded all the unicode fonts may be sound silly but it really worked for me.Here are my codes

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webView.loadUrl("http://kpbhandari.info/");
```