# String replace doesn't work when pass string through android webView JavascriptInterface

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I got a string replace issue when I pass Java String into android webView through JavaScriptInterface.

Below is the HTML (utf-8 file) inside the webView:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        a=window.MyAndroid.getPicEncStr(); //get string from Java side.        

        function getValue(){    
            b="ue";     

            if(a==b) {
                d="match";
            } else {
                d="not match";
            }

            c=d+":"+a.replace("u","0")+b.replace("u","0");
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=c;           
        }
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="test">test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScriptInterface code are below:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.content.Context;

public class JavaScriptInterface {

    private String unicodeToUtf8(String s) {
        String str=null;
        try {
            str=new String( s.getBytes("utf-8") , "utf-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

    public String getPicEncStr() {
        //return "ue"; //not work
        return this.unicodeToUtf8("ue"); //not work
    }
}
```

The result in span("id"="test") is "match:ue0e" when I call webView.loadUrl("javascript:getValue()") no matter I convert from "unicode" to "utf-8" or not.

Basically string "a" equals to string "b", but the replace function doesn't work on a, only works on b.

Could someone help me with that?

Thanks.

Comment: Try make the webView.loadUrl in utf8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892210/utf8-issue-in-android-webview-loadurl

Comment: Hi, Andrew, I tried, however, it still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I find a way to solve the problem:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        a=window.MyAndroid.getPicEncStr(); //get string from Java side.        

        function getValue(){    
            b="ue";     

            if(a==b) {
                d="match";
            } else {
                d="not match";
            }
            a=new String(a); //<-- force convert java string to javascript string.
            c=d+":"+a.replace("u","0")+b.replace("u","0");
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=c;           
        }
    </script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="test">test</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Still don't understand why. When I dump "a", it shows "**ue**", when I try to dump "a[0]", it shows "**undefined**", however "b[0]" is "**u**", I only can image Java/Javascript string are not compatible with each other, so, a explicit conversion is necessary.